# "Dovendosi dare" oppure "dovendo darsi"?

Tags: word-choice, difference, suffix

Sono assillato dal seguente dubbio:

si scrive "dovendosi dare" oppure "dovendo darsi"?
Cioè, il suffisso riflessivo va attaccato all'ausiliare/verbo modale o al verbo?

Secondo me, non importa dove uno lo metta, non ci ho mai fatto caso finora. Chiedo per avere una conferma (entrambe forme corrette?), in quanto non ho potuto trovare forum in cui si discuteva questo problema.

Ad esempio:

> L'ippopotamo, non **potendosi riparare/potendo ripararsi** dal freddo, morì congelato.

Comment: Purtroppo non ho trovato fonti per il caso specifico (verbo modale al gerundio + infinito) ma, in generale, la regola è che con i verbi modali il pronome riflessivo può andare sia prima che dopo il verbo principale quindi entrambe le forme dovrebbero essere corrette. C'è però da prestare attenzione all'ausiliare da utilizzare, nel caso in cui il verbo modale sia in un tempo composto: se il pronome riflessivo è prima del verbo principale, bisogna usare *essere* ("non *essendosi* potuto riparare") altrimenti si usa *avere* ("non *avendo* potuto ripararsi").

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Ho trovato un riferimento, anche se non so quanto "autorevole" lo si possa considerare, qui: https://www.italianoinonda.net/r039.shtml (paragrafo "Ausiliari di modo")

Comment: Per @secan o chi altro voglia formulare una risposta con una fonte sicuramente autorevole: ho caricato [qui](https://imgur.com/a/K93ySl3) la foto della pagina di _Italiano_ di Serianni in cui se ne parla. Purtroppo io non ho tempo.

Comment: Grazie @DaG, ho provato a mettere insieme una risposta che spero sia soddisfacente.

Comment: Grazie a te, @secan!

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

Entrambe le forme, "non potendosi riparare" e "non potendo ripararsi", sono corrette.
Occorre però notare che la posizione del pronome "si" influenza l'ausiliare da utilizzare nei tempi composti, richiedendo *essere* nel caso in cui preceda il verbo principale ("non *essendo**si*** potuto riparare") o *avere* nel caso in cui lo segua ("non *avendo* potuto riparar**si**").

## La regola grammaticale

Tratto da "Italiano", di Luca Serianni (ed. Garzanti):

> Quando l'infinito è preceduto da un verbo servile, il pronome atono può appoggiarsi in genere si al verbo reggente, come proclito, sia all'infinito, come enclito: "lo posso dire" o "posso dirlo".
> [...omissis...]
> Nei tempi composti l'ausiliare è quello dell'infinito quando il pronome atono è anteposto al verbo reggente ("non ci sono potuto entrare", perché si dice "sono entrato"), può essere quello richiesto dal verbo servile quando i pronome è enclitico ("non ho potuto entrarci", come si dice "ho potuto" assolutamente; ma è altrettanto corretto: "non sono potuto entrarci").
> [...omissis...]

[fonte (gentilmente fornita da @DaG): [foto della pagina](https://i.stack.imgur.com/44vfy.jpg)]

Stando a quanto riportato, anche la formulazione "non essendo potuto ripararsi" si potrebbe ritenere corretta. Tuttavia, in "Grammatica italiana", di Maurizio Dàrdano e Pietro Trifone (ed. Zanichelli), si può leggere:

> Se il riflessivo è accompagnato da un verbo servile, si ha l’ausiliare essere quando la particella pronominale è proclitica (si è voluto lavare), l’ausiliare avere quando è enclitica (ha voluto lavarsi).

[fonte indiretta: citazione nel [forum online "Cruscate"](https://www.achyra.org/cruscate/viewtopic.php?p=23391&sid=2cf9dc2d5d83cba5e2b9d00eac76e499#p23391)]

Questo escluderebbe la correttezza di "non essendo potuto ripararsi", suggerendo che *nel caso specifico dei verbi riflessivi*, non ci sia libertà di scelta nell'uso dell'ausiliare per i tempi composti.