# Ausiliare con verbi servili in presenza di un pronome atono: essere o avere?

Tags: verbs, grammar

1a)"Mi avrebbero dovuto essere dati "

2a)"mi sarebbero dovuti essere dati"

3a)'"Avrebbero dovuto essermi dati"

4a)"sarebbero dovuti essermi dati "

1b")Mi avrebbe dovuto venire a prendere "

2b)"mi sarebbe dovuto venire a prendere"

3b)"Avrebbe dovuto venirmi a prendere "

4b)"Sarebbe dovuto venirmi a prendere"

A me suonano un po' tutte, però  ho letto questo sul sito della crusca:

"Se l'infinito ha con sé un pronome atono (mi, si, ti, ci, vi) bisogna usare "essere" se il pronome è prima dell'infinito (es. "non si è voluto alzare"), "avere" se il pronome è dopo l'infinito (es. "non ha voluto alzarsi")."

Quindi, stando a ciò che c'è scritto, le frasi sicuramente corrette sono la 2 e la 3, "a" e "b".

Anche andando a cercare altre fonti venivano date le stesse risposte, eppure ho il dubbio che con questa regola si intendano solo pronomi atoni che svolgono una funzione riflessiva e in questo caso non mi pare che ce ne siano.
Se sostituiamo "mi" con "lo" viene fuori:

1c)"Lo avrebbe dovuto venire a prendere"

2c)" losarebbe dovuto venire a prendere"

3c)"Avrebbe dovuto venirlo a prendere

4)c "Sarebbe dovuto venirlo a prendere"

Sono molto confuso 
Aspetto con ansia una vostra risposta per avere le idee più chiare sulla correttezza delle frasi

Comment: Corretta o meno che sia, mi sarebbero dovuti essere dati (!) molti soldi per farmi scrivere una frase come “mi sarebbero dovuti essere dati” anziché, per esempio, “avrebbero dovuto darmi”, “dovrebbero avermi dato” o altri modi che evitino quattro voci verbali consecutive.

Comment: Anche se la domanda di partenza è differente, la risposta si può trovare in [questa discussione](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/13516/dovendosi-dare-oppure-dovendo-darsi#comment33025_13516): [...continua...]

Comment: [...] "_Quando l'infinito è preceduto da un verbo servile, il pronome atono può appoggiarsi in genere si al verbo reggente, come proclito, sia all'infinito, come enclito: "lo posso dire" o "posso dirlo". [...omissis...] **Nei tempi composti l'ausiliare è quello dell'infinito quando il pronome atono è anteposto al verbo reggente ("non ci sono potuto entrare", perché si dice "sono entrato"), può essere quello richiesto dal verbo servile quando i pronome è enclitico ("non ho potuto entrarci", come si dice "ho potuto" assolutamente; ma è altrettanto corretto: "non sono potuto entrarci")**._"